# How to catch UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username error?

Tags: python, django, forms

In my form, I get this whenever someone signs up with their username like that. How do i prevent the error from goign to a whole new yellow page and make it go back to the user and raise it as a forms error?

Comment: Sorry but this is not how you ask question in stackoverflow. You need to be specific, and most importantly, post some code you've tried. Your current description is too general and not helpful, there's no way for us to help you. Imagine I write an answer: you can just wrap your code in a `try except` and redirect to the same page with the form, then you render the errors in the page, that wouldn't be helpful either, right?

Comment: @ShangWang actually thats really helpful

Answer (score 1):

If the unique constraint is throwing the IntegrityError:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

try:
    user.save()
except IntegrityError as e: 
    if 'UNIQUE constraint' in e.message:
        #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is very easy just use django inbuilt AuthenticationForm

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)

if form.is_vaild():
   form.save()
else:
   # handle error
   # you can also use form.errors as message
```